# Show that the function $f:(0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x\sin{1/x}$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis

My professor gave the class a hint to try to find a continuous extension for this problem. In our textbook, *Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus* by Ross, one of the theorems states "A real-valued function $f$ on $(a,b)$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$ if and only if it can be extended to a continuous function $\tilde{f}$ on $[a,b]$."

Now, I have not had any trouble finding a continuous extension, but the fact that the domain in the problem is $(0,1]$ and not $(0,1)$ for some reason is making it difficult for me to figure out how to use the above theorem for this problem.

Does anyone have any hints? I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Could you compute $\lim_{x\to 0}x\sin(1/x)$

Answer (score 0):

Define $g: [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $$g(x) = \cases{x\sin(1/x) \quad \text{for } x\ne 0 \\ 0\quad\text{for }x=0}$$

$g$ is obviously continuous in $(0,1]$, and as $\sin(1/x)$ is bounded, $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} x\sin(1/x)=0=g(0),$$

so $g$ is continuous at $0$ too.

Now, $g$ is continuous at the compact set $[0,1]$, so the Heine Theorem gives us that $g$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$.

Let's prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1]$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. As $g$ is uniformly continuous, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that, for all $x,y\in [0,1]$ with $|x-y|<\delta$ we have $|g(x)-g(y)|<\varepsilon$.

In particular, if we take $x,y\in (0,1]$ (with $|x-y|<\delta$), $$|g(x)-g(y)|=|x\sin(1/x)-y\sin(1/y)|=|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$$

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes a lot more sense now! I greatly appreciate your help!